# How to configure decimal_mark and thousand_separator - Money Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

I'm trying use the `gem money-rails` but with no success.

I live in Brazil and here the decimal mark is "," and the thousand separator is "."

So, I add the follow code in a money.rb initializer:

```
MoneyRails.configure do |config|
    config.default_currency = :brl
    config.register_currency = {
        :id                  => :brl, 
        :priority            => 1,
        :iso_code            => "BRL",
        :name                => "Real",
        :symbol              => "R$",
        :symbol_first        => true,
        :subunit             => "Cent",
        :subunit_to_unit     => 100,
        :thousands_separator => ".",
        :decimal_mark        => ","
    }
end
```

And in my model class "Produto":

```
class Produto < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :nome, :preco
  monetize :preco_centavos
end
```

But when I try use this in Rails console I get a different behavior:

```
irb(main):001:0> p = Produto.new
=> #<Produto id: nil, nome: nil, preco_centavos: 0, preco_currency: "BRL", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> p.preco = 1000.to_money
=> #<Money fractional:100 currency:BRL>
irb(main):003:0> p.preco.format
=> "R$1,000.00"
```

The format method return "R$1,000.00" when I expect "R$1.000,00".

Someone already passed for this?

PS: Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug (or at least a misleading feature) in the `money-rails` gem code. Set `Money.use_i18n = false`.  Once you do this, then you won't need to do `config.register_currency` for the commas/decimals, at least.  `1000.to_money('BRL').format` yields `"R$1.000,00"`.

See https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/blob/4a35ae823843fba80c036e2332e80d6b9e06dcb5/lib/money-rails/active_model/validator.rb#L58 for why this is the case.

Comment: Thanks Julie! I fiz this for include _I18n.default_locale = :pt_ in application.rb file.
I will try your suggestion too.